# Container can't connect to MySql DB

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud

I have one container running MySQL and want to connect to the DB from another container (Wordpress). When running the container locally on my laptop it can connect to the DB running on Bluemix. Running the same container on Bluemix

```
ice run --name=wordpress1 -p 80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=xxx -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=129.41.234.102:3306 registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/rhocheck/wordpress:latest
```

I get this errors:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No route to host in - on line 10
```

The DB is up an running. I can connect even from a container on Bluemix I connected vie ssh

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ClearDB Service instead.  The MySQL service is experimental.  ClearDB is an awesome company that does hosted MySQL.  Could you try binding CLearDB to your app/container and connect via that way?

Comment: I am not talking about any Bluemix services. The mysql db is a Docker container too. The goal is having those two containers talk to each other.

Comment: Could you check that mysql has started on your second docker container and that it is not running on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: It is up and running. If I run the wordpress container locally, it can connect to the mysql db running in the other container. I also deployed an container just running a sshd server, intalled mysql-client, and was able to connect as well.

Comment: Can you try pinging the mysql container from the wordpress container?  Also try `telnet ipaddressofmysql 3306`.

Comment: I can't ssh to the wordpress container though I ran it with ssh and my key. ssh to the same container running locally works.

Comment: Can you deploy your wordpress container with your ssh key so we can debug what is going on?

Comment: I ran it with this command: ice run --name=wordpress1 -p 80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=xxx -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=129.41.234.102:3306 registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/rhocheck/wp_sshd --ssh "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" but can't connect via ssh

Comment: I was just able to hit your machine... 

`[08:44 AM] jsloyer@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro [~]>telnet 129.41.234.102 3306
Trying 129.41.234.102...
Connected to 129.41.234.102.
Escape character is '^]'.
_
5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log^|tS!G%!??q=xfu;b^3"PJmysql_native_password^CConnection closed by foreign host.`  

To me it looks like na issue with your wordpress docker image...

Comment: I think so too but why does it work when it runs locally? It is the standard wordpress image from the docker registry. Not based on one of the IBM images. Could this be an issue?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue.  It's hard to debug this without having CLI access to the VM, could you try getting the SSH key first to work so we can get on the container and see whats going on?

Comment: I managed to get ssh access. Right after ice restart I can ssh to the container and manually start apche2-forground which brings up wordpress. But if I wait little longer network seems to be dead for this container.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?